# when I'm trying install appodeal pod get error

Tags: macos, installation, cocoapods

I'm trying to install appodeal with cocoapods but I get an error.

I install about 9 frameworks, but only this framework getting the error. Here is code:

```
od install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AXRatingView (1.0.3)
Installing Appodeal (1.3.3)

[!] Error installing Appodeal
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/br/56_l2gp52_d7zcv_tqyf_fkw0000gn/T/d20170131-599-1psuk5j/file.zip https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/appodeal-ios/1.3.3/pods/Appodeal.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  9  258M    9 23.5M    0     0  23849      0  3:09:22  0:17:14  2:52:08     0curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

Here is an image of the error:

[image: POD INSTALL ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

after trying a lot times its now installed

Thanks an sorry

here is solution: `pod install --no-repo-update`

Answer (score 0):

To download and incorporate the Appodeal iOS SDK into your project using Cocoapods, add the following line to your project's Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'   

target 'Name' do
pod 'Appodeal', '1.3.7'
end
```

If you have problems with versions of pods please run

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update
```